# Logical Question - display numbers in specific formats

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist, logic

I have one problem and trying to resolve it . I need to arrange the numbers in certain format in java.
Lets say example  I have arraylist of object Org. Org has attribute like orgId,AppYear,OrgName,OrgCityState. I have Populated list like below:

```
public List<Org> createList()
{
    List<Org> lst = new ArrayList<>();
    
    Org org = new Org();
    org.setOrgId(1l);
    org.setAppYear("1995");
    org.setOrgName("abc");
    org.setOrgCityState("Ahd Gujarat");
    lst.add(org);
    org = new Org();
    org.setOrgId(1l);
    org.setAppYear("1996");
    org.setOrgName("abc");
    org.setOrgCityState("Ahd Gujarat");
    lst.add(org);
    
    org = new Org();
    org.setOrgId(1l);
    org.setAppYear("1997");
    org.setOrgName("abc");
    org.setOrgCityState("Ahd Gujarat");
    lst.add(org);
    
    org = new Org();
    org.setOrgId(1l);
    org.setAppYear("2000");
    org.setOrgName("abc");
    org.setOrgCityState("Ahd Gujarat");
    lst.add(org);
    
    org = new Org();
    org.setOrgId(1l);
    org.setAppYear("2002");
    org.setOrgName("abc");
    org.setOrgCityState("Ahd Gujarat");
    lst.add(org);
    
    org = new Org();
    org.setOrgId(1l);
    org.setAppYear("2004");
    org.setOrgName("abc");
    org.setOrgCityState("Ahd Gujarat");
    lst.add(org);
    
    org = new Org();
    org.setOrgId(1l);
    org.setAppYear("2005");
    org.setOrgName("abc");
    org.setOrgCityState("Ahd Gujarat");
    lst.add(org);
    
    org = new Org();
    org.setOrgId(2l);
    org.setAppYear("2002");
    org.setOrgName("abc");
    org.setOrgCityState("Baroda Gujarat");
    lst.add(org);
    
    org = new Org();
    org.setOrgId(2l);
    org.setAppYear("2004");
    org.setOrgName("abc");
    org.setOrgCityState("Baroda Gujarat");
    lst.add(org);
    
    
    org = new Org();
    org.setOrgId(2l);
    org.setAppYear("2005");
    org.setOrgName("abc");
    org.setOrgCityState("Baroda Gujarat");
    lst.add(org);
    
    
    return lst;
    

}
```

AS you can see in the data Only AppYear and OrgId Is different. I need to arrange this data Based on continuous year. lets say as Example if year is 1995,1996,1997,2000,2003,2004,2005, 2008 .. it should show it something like

```
 AyyYear                   | OrgID | OrgName | CityState
1995-1997,2000,2003-2005,2008 |  1    | abc     | ahd Gujarat
2002,2004-2005                |  2    | abc     | Baroda Gujarat.
```

so basically need to concate different year in certain range as i shown above.
I tried creating logic but not successful. I took two for loops compare the each organization . for same organization , i try to concate the years but seems like its overriding it and not coming in the format . I have difficulty breaking the loop and concate data when organization is changed.
Hope , I have provided correct information.
Jordan

Comment: Can you share the code you've produced so far and explain where exactly you're having difficulties?

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```java
static String formatRanges(int... values) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0, j; i < values.length; i++) {
        for (j = i; j + 1 < values.length && values[j] + 1 == values[j + 1]; j++);
        if (i != 0) buf.append(',');
        buf.append(values[i]);
        if (j > i) buf.append('-').append(values[i = j]);
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

*Test*

```java
System.out.println(formatRanges(2,3,4,7,10,11,12,15,18));
```

*Output*

```
2-4,7,10-12,15,18
```

Comment: I have try to explain the issue I am facing with code. Please open my question for answer.

Comment: @Jordan Since a result row in your new question can't have multiple values for `OrgID`, `OrgName`, and `CityState`, you first need to group the data by those values. For each group you will then have a list of year numbers, and can therefore apply this answer to those year values.

Comment: I tried doing that. I took Hashmap<orgId,List<Org>> but couldnt iterate with above logic not sure why .I changed length with size of the arraylist but unable to figure out where I made mistake.